# The code gets executed even if condition is false

Tags: jquery

I was struggling with this whole afternoon and I can't proceed any further without any help.

Straight to the point.

```
// On document ready
$(function() {
    var stop = false;
    $('#update-cart :input').on('change input', function() {
        // Here you go
        stop = true;
    });

    if (stop === false) {
        // For some(silly) reason It gets executed on input field change 
    }
});
```

If I understand that correctly the code above proceed with `if` statement unless there is some change in input fields whereas it sets new variable. So the `if` condition remains false. I don't understand why it gets executed if condition is false. I may be missing or doing something wrong though.

Comment: Your `stop = true` is inside an event handler.  It will only run when your input changes.  So your code is: 1 set stop = false, 2 initiate an event handler to run later, 3 check if stop is false, which is clearly will be

Comment: It will execute everytime at first because at first is always false and you run the if condition .... if you want to evaluate just on change then move your if statement inside

Comment: @DaniP Thanks! I need both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the code **in** the handler is run (and re-run) when the event occurs.

Here's the order your code runs in:

1. Create `stop` variable and set it to `false`.
2. Hook up the `change` and `input` handler.
3. Check `if (stop === false)` and, since that's true, execute the code in the `if`'s block.
4. Later, whenever the value changes, set `stop` to `true`. Which has no effect whatsoever on the code that ran in Step #3.

Comment: I was also logging the process into console and this is the order. Any pointer or workaround on How to stop execution of the `if` statement?

Comment: @The `if` statement doesn't continually run, it runs **once**, when the function it's in is called by the jQuery `ready` stuff. If you want it to be called at a different time, move the code there. If you need it to run both when `ready` fires *and* every time there's a change, I recommend putting it in a function and calling that function from both places.